# Authenticate to multiple Azure services using Service Principle (.net Core)

Tags: azure, authentication, asp.net-core, azureservicebus, azure-keyvault

I need to get access to **Key Vault** and **Service Bus** from code, using a *Service Principle* for authentication.

I can use the following code to access Service Bus, which works as expected - when I enable to *Service Principle* in the *Access Policies* I can pull the list of topics:

```
var credentials = SdkContext.AzureCredentialsFactory.FromServicePrincipal(APPID, APPSECRET, TENANTID, AzureEnvironment.AzureGlobalCloud);

var serviceBusManager = ServiceBusManager.Authenticate(credentials, SUBSCRIPTIONID);
var serviceBusNamespace = serviceBusManager.Namespaces.List().SingleOrDefault(n => n.Name == "SERVICEBUSNAMESPACE");
var topics = serviceBusNamespace.Topics.ListAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
```

However, I also need to get some information from Key Vault and I was trying to establish a common way to authenticate.

**METHOD 1**

Similar to the above, I tried this code to access KeyVault:

```
var credentials = SdkContext.AzureCredentialsFactory.FromServicePrincipal(APPID, APPSECRET, TENANTID, AzureEnvironment.AzureGlobalCloud);

var kvManager = new KeyVaultClient(credentials);
var secret = kvManager.GetSecretAsync("https://VAULTNAMESPACE.vault.azure.net", "SECRETNAME").GetAwaiter().GetResult().Value;
```

I get the the following error:

> Microsoft.Azure.KeyVault.Models.KeyVaultErrorException: 'Operation
>   returned an invalid status code 'Unauthorized''

**METHOD 2**

This code does work for Key Vault however (showing I have correct permissions):

```
string GetSecret()
{
     var client = new KeyVaultClient(GetAccessToken);
     var secret = client.GetSecretAsync("https://VAULTNAMESPACE.vault.azure.net", "SECRETNAME").GetAwaiter().GetResult();
     return secret;
}

private static async Task<string> GetAccessToken(string authority, string resource, string scope)
{
     var context = new AuthenticationContext("https://login.windows.net/" + tenantId);
     var credential = new ClientCredential(appId, appSecret);
     var tokenResult = await context.AcquireTokenAsync("https://vault.azure.net", credential);
     return tokenResult.AccessToken;
}
```

But, again, it's a very KeyVault specific way to Authenticate and I was hoping to establish a common mechanism using *SdkContext.AzureCredentialsFactory*.  Any reason why I'd be getting an *Unauthorized* exception with the code above connecting to Key Vault?  (all is set up correctly in Azure).

Thanks for any tips!

Comment: Maybe you haven't added the SP access via the Key Vault's Access Policies? It's a common thing people forget, that Key Vault has its own authorization system.

Comment: Updated code so it's clearer - method 2 works for me, showing the Service Principle I'm using to access does have the correct permissions BUT method 1 is preferable as I can use it to also access Service Bus (and other services) and I want a common way to authenticate.  HOWEVER, method 1 yields an Unauthorized exception.  I dont understand the inner workings of the FromServicePrincipal call but it seems like it's scope might not match that of method 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `SdkContext.AzureCredentialsFactory.FromServicePrincipal` to authenticate, it will use `https://management.azure.com/` as its Resource Uri.

While Azure Key Vault has its own authorization system and its Resource Uri is `https://vault.azure.net`, so you may get the `Unauthorized` error message.

So, you could use Method2 to get access to Azure Key Vault with right Resource Uri.

For more details, you could refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/azure/dotnet-sdk-azure-authenticate?view=azure-dotnet).